# Hello World in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I just started learning C++, and I found a code that doesn't work.  It shows me red lines on `"std_lib_facilities.h"` and on `cout`.

I found this code in this book "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++" by Bjarne Stroustrup.

do you recommend another book I have some experience with python and I want to move to c++
thank you

```
// This program outputs the message “Hello, World!” to the monitor
#include "std_lib_facilities.h"
int main() // C++ programs start by executing the function main
{
 cout << "Hello, World!\n"; // output “Hello, World!”
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "doesn't work". Does it not compile, does it crash, does it output something weird, does it do something else?

Comment: _"... that doesn't work ..."_ in what way? You need to tell us.

Comment: What is the error you see?

Comment: Where did you find the code?

Comment: You probably have not copied `std_lib_facilities.h` to the same folder as your code or set the include directory of your compiler to find it. With that said any working compiler will tell you it can't find the header.

Comment: ***do you recommend another book*** No that is a good book. I don't particularly like the `std_lib_facilities.h` usage with that said however the book itself is recommended.

Comment: ***It shows me red lines on "std_lib_facilities.h" and on cout.*** It should also tell you that it can't find the header file. If it does not tell you this it is horribly broken and its time to get a different IDE. I recommend Visual Studio Community 2019 over any other IDE including Visual Studio Code (completely different product with a similar name) on MS Windows if that is your platform.

Comment: yes I use Visual Studio

Comment: Then you are not reading the error messages, the compiler should have clearly indicated it can't find the header. Note that `std_lib_facilities.h` is not a file that comes with your compiler. You have to install it yourself and if you don't put it in the same folder as your code you will have to adjust the compilers include path to find it in whatever other folder you put it in.

Comment: ok thank you very much for your help and your time, do you recommend me to continue learning using this book

Comment: Here is how you set the Include Directory in Visual Studio Community: [https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/588022/Using-Additional-Include-Directories](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/588022/Using-Additional-Include-Directories) this help is for an older version of Visual Studio but the setting is the same.

Comment: My second tip is to look at the errors in the Output Tab of Visual Studio after you compile. Often the text of the output tab is more verbose than the Errors List. I have as a professional developer disabled the errors list by default and instead I exclusively use the Output Tab.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include `<iostream>` to use `cout`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: “std_lib_facilities.h” is a header provided by Bjarne Stroustrup to make it easier for beginners to write C++ code, it pulls in the core stuff, including `std;;cout`. You’re right that a well-formed question would use the standard headers, but that’s not the solution to the (unspecified) problem here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `#include <iostream>` and a tip is to also type `using namespace std;` so you can use `cin` without typing `std::cin`

Comment: The `std_lib_facilities.h` file does that for you.

Comment: The part of the answer inside of `<` `>` doesn't show up. Surround it with backticks (`) to format it as code.

Comment: Teaching beginners to use `using namespace std` might arguably not be the best idea. Better `using std::cin`.

Comment: I'm a student. Personally it helped me saving time not writing std::